# Perl: including/embedding a module in a script

Tags: perl, module

I have a script that uses a subclass that I've written of a module from CPAN for presentation. I would ideally like to have the two in the same file, as there isn't much code in the subclassed module. It doesn't make sense to expand either the subclassed module to include the script's code, or to turn the script into a module. How should I include the module code in the script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No problems with having several packages in one file.

```
package Foo;

sub new {
    print "Foo::new\n";
}

package main;

new Foo;
```

Comment: I'd made the mistake of not removing the 'use Foo' declaration from the 'main' package. Thanks!

Comment: Not that there are any here, but lexical variables (`my ...;` and `our ...;`) declared in `Foo` will be visible in `main`.  If you do not want this, surround the package with curly braces: `{package Foo; ... }`

Comment: my() is for lexical variables. our() is for _package_ variables, though its effect is lexical.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `package` can be limited to a lexical block.  So you can do `{package Foo;  sub bar { 'blah' } } # Back in package 'main' here!`

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is following, name the 'module' you want to include `core.pm` or something like this. And then put it in the same directory as the other script and in the script put `require core;`, this should work. Generally have a look into `use` and `require` which should help you achieve what you want in one way or another.

Comment: This is the current arrangement; I have the module and the script in the same directory. I'd like them to be in the same file, though, since the module code is so short.

Comment: oh I didn't quite get your answer. Well then have a look at the answer above by Roman. You can just put the package in the script...